# Why does it seem like my class variable gets overwritten when i make a new object from that class?

Tags: java, processing

When i run the code, my first instance of Me, seems to be getting the seconds instances direct variable, that's not the point. Can someone tell me why it happens?
The program right now spawns 3 circles in the middle of the screen, supposedly moving in 3 different directions. But the two circles from the class overlaps and move in the same direction. Despite the objects originally receiving different Vectorcoordinates.
Thanks a lot in advance :)
Code:

```
PVector direct1 = new PVector(1,1);
PVector pos1;
ArrayList<Me> m; 
PVector di1 = new PVector(random(-1,1),random(-1,1));

void setup(){
 size(800,800);
 pos1 = new PVector(width/2,height/2);
 m = new ArrayList<Me>(0);
 for(int i =0; i< 2; i++){
   int a = int(random(-90,90));
  m.add(new Me(di1.rotate(radians(a)))); 
 }
}
void draw(){
 background(0); 
 fill(255);
 circle(pos1.x,pos1.y,50);
 pos1.add(direct1);
 for(int i =0; i< m.size(); i++){
  m.get(i).drawMe(); 
  m.get(i).move();
  //println(m.get(i).direct);
 }
}
class Me{
  PVector pos;
  PVector direct;
 Me(PVector oldDir){
  pos = new PVector(width/2,height/2);
  this.direct = oldDir;
  //this.direct.rotate(radians(random(-90-90)));
  println(direct);

 }
 void drawMe(){
   fill(60);
   circle(pos.x,pos.y,50);
 }
 void move(){
   //println(this.direct);
   pos.add(this.direct);
   println(direct);
 }
}
```

Comment: You create only one instance of `PVector di1` and pass this one instance into all of your `Me` constructors. If you want your `Me` instances to have different instances of `di1` you need to create them.

Comment: A sidenote: your code is very unreadable. You should come up with some reasonable names. What is `Me`, `di1`, `pos1`, `direct1`? What is the difference between `pos` and `pos1`?

Comment: Im sry this is just some example code, quickly made to isolate and illustrate the problem. The problem is based on a larger projekt, where i have tried to recreate astroides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Me` objects have the same *instance* of `PVector`.

This code demonstrates the problem:

```
PVector a = new PVector(1, 1);
PVector b = a;
a.rotate(3.14);
println(b);
```

To resolve this you should instead pass a `copy` of the vector:

```
PVector a = new PVector(1, 1);
PVector b = a.copy();
a.rotate(3.14);
println(b);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped fixing my problem